# display getTextAttribute in custom tab

Tags: attributes

I added custom tab in product page and then showed necessary information in custom file with name: customtabinfo.phtml, now i need display attrubutes, but when i try get attribute:
`<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute'); ?>` - i see error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object.

How i can display my attribute?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or can try:

```
<?php 

$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('latitude');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
?>
```

it's also working =)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
Mage::registry('current_product')->getAttributeText('custom_attribute');
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally in your custom block for your phtml you should do

```
public function getProduct(){
    if(!$this->product){
       $this->product = Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
    return $this->product;
}
```

Then in your phtml

```
echo $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('custom_attribute')
```